# Extent of ATC control on an aircraft

Tags: air-traffic-control, flight-controls, aircraft-systems

Are there any systems in a manned aircraft which can be controlled by the ATC/ground control.

To be specific, could you name some tested and existing procedures/systems which make it possible to change aircraft dynamics such that it is manipulated from outside the cockpit of the aircraft and the pilot is overridden?

Comment: @fooot: Thanks! :)
But that question only debates the risks of such a system. I ask whether any existing flight system has been tested for this capability.

Comment: The risks are all the reasons why it hasn't been built or tested for manned aircraft.

Comment: @fooot: So it hasn't been done, and does not pose a security risk on current aircraft?

Comment: A system that allows external control to override will be fairly unpopular with pilots.

Comment: There is one system with is controlled by the ground, but the pilot can shut it down. A current popular trend is to prevent this pilot action in the future, because many people think the pilot is not reliable. This system is the [SSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_surveillance_radar) transponder which replies to SSR interrogations.

Comment: @mins: I wanted an answer like this. Could you substantiate? Any text/document?

Comment: It is not a positive answer to your question "*possible to change aircraft dynamics*", rather it shows ATC actions are actually very limited to interrogations and can't interfere with piloting AFAIK. I can expand and document in this direction if you want. But the question needs first to be reopened.

Comment: Nothing on board a manned aircraft can be controlled from outside. The only people that control it will be both pilots in the cockpit. ATC now has only the capability in knowing your ssr mode c or mode s that gives them information about your current altitude and speed